# Server won't give ItemStack when a Player joins

Tags: java, bukkit

I have created an ItemStack which should be given to players when they join, but it doesn't work as expected.

Here is my attempt:

```
public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener{



public void onEnable(){
    Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
    registerListeners();
}

private void registerListeners() {
    PluginManager pm = Bukkit.getPluginManager();
}

public static void giveItems(Player p) {

}


@EventHandler
public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e) {
    Player p = e.getPlayer();
    ItemStack t = new ItemStack(Material.TNT, 1);
    ItemMeta tmeta = t.getItemMeta();
    tmeta.setDisplayName("§cTNT §7(Right click to use)");
    t.setItemMeta(tmeta);

    for(Player pl : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()){


    p.getInventory().setItem(4, t);
    p.getInventory().addItem(t);
    }
}



@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@EventHandler
public void onRightClick(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
    if(e.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR || e.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) {
        if(e.getItem() != null && e.getItem().getType() == Material.TNT) {
            Player p = e.getPlayer();
            TNTPrimed tnt = (TNTPrimed) p.getWorld().spawn(p.getLocation(), TNTPrimed.class);
            tnt.setVelocity(p.getLocation().getDirection().normalize().multiply(1));
            p.updateInventory();
```

And it failed.
How can I successfully give ItemStacks to Players when they join the server?

Answer (score 0):

Uh, why are you looping through all players in the server when you already have the player you want to give the item to in the variable `p`? You're also not using proper chat color codes.

Use this instead:

```
// Imports and other code here...

@EventHandler
public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e){
    Player p = e.getPlayer();
    ItemStack t = new ItemStack(Material.TNT);
    ItemMeta tmeta = t.getItemMeta();
    tmeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.RED + "TNT " + ChatColor.GRAY + "(Right click to use)");
    t.setItemMeta(tmeta);
    p.getInventory().addItem(t);
}
```

Other than that, I don't see anything wrong with your setup.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into your code the following mistakes should be corrected:

- Remove the useless method registerLiteners() and all of its calls. The method doesn't really do anything.
- You should not interate all online players to add the ItemStack to your Player.

Second of all: from your question, what I can understand as your situation is: **you want a player to join the server and receive an item for that**. The way you're handling it is that everytime a player joins the server, he will get items added to his inventory for every player online in the server. The situation you're probably in is that you're testing the plugin on your own, and there is no player online when you join, what leads to no items being given.

---

---

All things considered, the correct way to **get your intended behaviour** should be the following:

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e) {
    Player joined = e.getPlayer();
    ItemStack itemToAdd = new ItemStack(Material.TNT);
    ItemMeta stackMeta = itemToAdd.getItemMeta();
    stackMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.RED + "TNT " + ChatColor.GRAY + "(Right click to use)");    //Using ChatColor is recommended over § character.
    itemToAdd.setItemMeta(stackMeta);
    joined.getInventory().addItem(itemToAdd);
}
```

The event will add your custom itemstack to the player's inventory after he joins the server.

---

---

It's also important to point out that, although it's not part of your question, your PlayerInteractEvent should be fixed to only listen to your custom ItemStack. It will be fired with any TnT held.

Comment: I changed my code to what have you've said, but still they don't get any TNT? I have also checked the other plugin that adds an item when a player joins and disabled it but that didn't do a differance.

Comment: @InfernoArtz When I'm testing, it works as intended. Take a look at my full  code:http://pastebin.com/EsRdVbAG